# Listing all events from all calendars

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm attempting to use the Tizen SDK on a Gear S3 in order to list all events in the calendar. When I attempt to do this, I receive 0 events even though I the in built Calendar widget lists multiple. When I enumerate and list the Calendar Books, I only receive the 3 default books (events, todos, birthdays). How do I access the calendar books from other accounts such as active sync, google, live, etc? The following is how I'm iterating over the books (no errors are received):

```
    calendar_error_e error = CALENDAR_ERROR_NONE;
calendar_connect();
calendar_list_h list = NULL;
error = calendar_db_get_all_records(_calendar_book._uri, 0, 0, &list);

char* outstr1 = NULL;
char* outstr2 = NULL;
char* outstr3 = NULL;

calendar_record_h record = NULL;
error = calendar_list_get_current_record_p(list, &record);
error = calendar_record_get_str_p (record, _calendar_book.name, &outstr1);
error = calendar_list_next(list);
error = calendar_list_get_current_record_p(list, &record);
error = calendar_record_get_str_p (record, _calendar_book.name, &outstr2);
error = calendar_list_next(list);
error = calendar_list_get_current_record_p(list, &record);
error = calendar_record_get_str_p (record, _calendar_book.name, &outstr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are using these Guides as Reference:

[Calendar Native Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/personal-data/calendar)

[Calendar API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SOCIAL__CALENDAR__SVC__MODULE.html)

Along with creating calendar event using gear, I also tried creating events using Calendar API. But It seems I'm not also able to retrieve events.

[create_event](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/personal-data/calendar#create_event)

[retrieve_event](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/personal-data/calendar#get_event)

If we aren't missing something this might be a bug. You may report a bug on [Tizen bug Tracker](https://bugs.tizen.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa). Here’s a guideline on [how to report bugs](https://www.tizen.org/community/bug-tracker/how-report-bugs?langswitch=en&langredirect=1). Share your progress and the 'Reported bug' link here on this post to help keep track.

About google/live calendar, I'm not sure If they're treated as different calendar_books.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the Calendar API using both web and the new .NET and have the same results so I wrote a little test where I created my own events using the new API. Those were stored and could later be retrieved, however they did not show up in the S3 Samsung calendar app.

It is likely that the Samsung app is proprietary and uses the Samsung Android app with its own cache on the watch and is not integrated with the Calendar API, at least not on Gear S3. Makes sense since the Samsung calendar app has been available since Tizen 2.3 that has no Calendar API on wearable profile.